# Proper way to access a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have a dataframe like this.

```
     Date          Open          High           Low         Close  \
0  2009-08-25  20246.789063  20476.250000  20143.509766  20435.240234   

      Adj Close      Volume  
0  20435.240234  1531430000
```

Using attribute or explicit naming both give me the same output:

```
sum(data.Date==data['Date']) == data.shape[0]

True
```

However I cannot access columns that are named with white space, like `'Adj Close'` with `df.columnname`, but can do with `df['columnname']`.

Is using `df['columnname']` strictly better than using `df.columnname` ?

Comment: `df['columnname']` is better than `df.`, sometime you will find the` '_'` or even when you have a name called 'max', you can only using df['max'] to get it, base on my understanding , `.` is for pipeline. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `.` as a column accessor is a convenience.  There are many limitations beyond having spaces in the name.  For example, if your column is named the same as an existing dataframe attribute or method, you won't be able to use it with a `.`.  A non-exhaustive list is `mean`, `sum`, `index`, `values`, `to_dict`, etc.  You also cannot reference columns with numeric headers via the `.` accessor.

So, yes, `['col']` is strictly better than `.col` because it is more consistent and reliable.